# How do you create system variables via batch file for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, environment-variables

How can I create a batch file which creates a new system variable?

(You know, in advanced system settings > environment variables > System Variables).

I want to create a new variable named `FLEXLM_TIMEOUT` and set its value to `10000000`.

I need to figure out a way to create this variable in an automated fashion as I have around one hundred computers that need this fix.

Comment: Corporate IT issues are off topic.

Comment: @CharlieRB This is a question about usage of Windows which is on-topic.

Comment: @KevinPanko Sorry. I see it differently. The [help] specifically states *"issues specific to corporate IT support and networks*" are [off topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). If the question didn't state "I have around 100 computers that need this fix", I'd probably agree with you.

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for the [SetX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) command:

```
 setx FLEXLM_TIMEOUT "10000000" /m
```

Should do what you are wanting.

This command has been standard in Windows since Vista and XP had it available in the `XP Support Tools`. It also has the ability to set variables on remote machines if needed.

Comment: see also: [Set windows environment variables with in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21606502/108350)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to create a .REG file for the path 
*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment*

The script should be:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\Environment] "FLEXLM_TIMEOUT"="10000000"

You don't even need to write the script from scratch: on a PC that has the variable, in *Regedit*, highlight the key *Environment* and in the *File* menu select *Export...*. The .REG file created will contain other values than FLEXLM_TIMEOUT, which need to be deleted by editing the file in Notepad.

Merging that file in will not delete the existing values; REGEDIT performs a true merge.